# Is the octahedral axiom really equivalent to the 4 x 4 lemma?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, triangulated-categories

$\require{AMScd}$I make reference to [this](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/PAPERS/AddJan01.pdf) paper. I've recently become aware that there's an annoying variety of a priori distinct (but "known" to be equivalent up to adding other hypotheses) definitions of triangulated categories, partly because allegedly no one knows an example of a weakly but not "strongly" triangulated category. Anyway, as part of all this I need to check the following assertion from May, in the linked paper: (I apologise for using photos but these and later commutative diagrams are beyond my abilities to draw in LaTex)

> [image]

This, together with the basic TR1) and TR2) axioms (rotation and existence, isomorphism-invariance of triangles), are claimed to imply the weak form of the classical octahedral axiom. May gives the following hint:

[image]

And... it **almost** works. It's so close to working but there's a final wrinkle which just does not seem to work. *I'm left wondering if May made an oversight about this final wrinkle or if I'm just missing an easy last step - this is my question.* If anyone has a reference for this equivalence (appropriately stated?) please say. I would like to note that some work of Neeman concerning mapping cones and the concept of “good” morphism shows that a (much?) (seemingly?) stronger notion of the 4 x 4 is equivalent to the octahedral axiom; May seems to claim we can make do with less.

So let $X\overset{f}{\to}Y\overset{g}{\to}Z$ be some composable morphisms, $h$ their composite. So extend $f,g,h$ to distinguished triangles: $$\begin{align}&X\overset{f}{\to}Y\overset{f'}{\to}U\overset{f''}{\to}\Sigma X\\&Y\overset{g}{\to}Z\overset{g'}{\to}W\overset{g''}{\to}\Sigma Y\\&X\overset{h}{\to}Z\overset{h'}{\to}V\overset{h''}{\to}\Sigma X\end{align}$$

The octahedral axiom in its weakest form tasks us with finding fillers $\alpha,\beta$ making the following a distinguished triangle: $$U\overset{\exists \alpha}{\to}V\overset{\exists\beta}{\to}W\overset{\Sigma(f')\circ g''}{\to}\Sigma U$$And such that the following commute:

> $$f''=h''\circ\alpha,\,g'=\beta\circ h',\,\alpha\circ f'=h'\circ g,\,g''\circ\beta=\Sigma(f)\circ h''$$

The latter two involve four morphisms. Using May's hint, I can find $\alpha,\beta$ such that **all but one** of these commute, the difficulty in making both quadrilaterals join up simultaneously. Did May make an oversight, do I need an extra hypothesis to make it tick, or am I missing an easy final resolution?

Specifically, I can find $\alpha,\alpha':U\to V,\beta,\beta':V\to W$ such that:

> The triangles $U\to V\to W\overset{\Sigma(f)\circ h''}{\to}\Sigma U$ are distinguished; $f''=h''\circ\alpha=h''\circ\alpha',g'=\beta\circ h'=\beta'\circ h'$;
>
> And $\alpha\circ f'=h'\circ g$ or $g''\circ\beta'=\Sigma(f)\circ h''$ but seemingly I can't make both hold for one pair $(\alpha,\beta)$ or $(\alpha',\beta')$ simultaneously.
>
> We can also find an automorphism $\gamma:V\cong V$ such that $\alpha'=\gamma\circ\alpha,\,\beta'\circ\gamma=\beta$ but isomorphism is *not* equality ! And I don't think this is good enough to conclude. Because inserting $\gamma$ anywhere into the picture could potentially alter the other, *fixed* morphisms given to us.

What to do?